# How to dynamically add rows with a dynamically generated table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code.

```
arrayToTable = function(data, options = {}){
    var table = $('<table />'),
        thead,
        tfoot,
        rows = [],
        row,
        i, j,
        defaults = {
            th: true, // should we use th elemenst for the first row
            thead: false, //should we incldue a thead element with the first row
            tfoot: false, // should we include a tfoot element with the last row
            attrs: {} // attributes for the table element, can be used to
        }

    options = $.extend(defaults, options);

    table.attr(options.attrs)

    // loop through all the rows, we will deal with tfoot and thead later
    for(i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
        row = $('<tr />');
        for(j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++){
            if(i == 0 && options.th){
                row.append($('<th />').html(data[i][j]));
            }else{
                row.append($('<td />').html("<input type='text' name='fname'>"));
            }
        }
        rows.push(row);
    }

    // if we want a thead use shift to get it
    if(options.thead){
        thead = rows.shift();
        thead = $('<thead />').append(thead);
        table.append(thead);
    }

    // if we want a tfoot then pop it off for later use
    if(options.tfoot){
        tfoot = rows.pop();
    }

    // add all the rows
    for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        table.append(rows[i]);
    };

    // and finally add the footer if needed
    if(options.tfoot){
        tfoot = $('<tfoot />').append(tfoot);
        table.append(tfoot);
    }
    return table;
}

    var data = [
        ['Name', 'Age', 'Email'],
        ['John Doe', '27', 'john@doe.com'],
        ['Jane Doe', '29', 'jane@doe.com']
    ];

    var table = arrayToTable(data, {
        thead: true,
        attrs: {class: 'table'}
    })

    $('body').append(table);
```

and it produces this:

http://jsfiddle.net/bytg16k6/

I need a button to dinamycally add new rows to it, but I am stuck with that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You table has a class (can have an id if you have multiple tables with this class), then you can use the following code on click of a button with class 'add-row':

```
$('.add-row').on('click', function () {
    $('.table').append('<tr><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td></tr>');
  });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bytg16k6/1/

Please note the above code is just an example of a way to do this.